# JavaScript toString or join on Array of long numbers (SSN)

Tags: javascript, arrays, string, string-formatting

Is there a way in javascript to ensure plain number-to-string conversion (not scientific notation) while converting a mixed set of object types to strings?

I am writing javascript functions to format pre-existing data of social security numbers. The problem I can't get past is converting an array of numbers, 9 digits in length, to an array of strings. When I use the following function:

```
function arrayTo1d(arr){
    /*
        Returns a 1D array of strings from the given array
    */
    try {
        return arr.join().split(",");
    } catch (err) {
        return ["Datatype Error"];
    }
}
```

It gives an array of strings in scientific notation like: 1.23456789E8

I need the number to be a string as the original display: 123456789

To add to the problem, the array elements are sometimes a mix of strings, numbers, or objects, so `toString()`, or in this case, `join().split(",")` is the 'catch-all' fix. When an array contains a string, `'123-45-6789'`, and a number, `123456789`, the function above should merge everything to a 1D array of strings regardless of individual element types, giving `[...,'123-45-6789','123456789']` but instead I get `[...,'123-45-6789','1.23456789E8']`.

Additional Notes:

```
Object.prototype.toString.call(ssnObj).slice(8,-1);
```

returns 'JavaArray'

And:

```
Object.prototype.toString.call(ssnObj[0]).slice(8,-1);
```

returns 'JavaObject'

> EDIT:
>
> I am using Informer JavaScript, which is interpreted internally by Java. It seems that for this reason, I am getting the scientific notation whereas in node.js, I do NOT get the notation. Quote from Informer's wiki:
>
> "**Informer JavaScript vs. “Normal” JavaScript**
>   Normal JavaScript is typically embedded in HTML and is interpreted by the browser. This means that “normal” JavaScript can affect things on the actual HTML document that is rendered. Informer JavaScript is actually embedded within and interpreted by the Informer Java application. Once interpreted, the results are passed to the browser. This means that Informer JavaScript cannot affect the HTML document that is viewed in the browser. It can, however, do everything else that JavaScript can do." -[source: Informer wiki - Columns](http://www.entrinsik.com/support/informer/40wiki/index.php/Columns)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not observing the scientific notation conversion when converting a number such as 999999999 into a string.

```
999999999 + ''   // = "999999999"
"999999999" + '' // = "999999999"
```

If I'm correct, you would like a function that takes `999999999` or `"999999999"` or `"999-99-9999"` and returns `"999999999"`? as a string?

```
function formatSSN(ssn) {
  return (ssn + '').replace(/[^\d]/g, '');
}
```

You can then use it to transform your array:

```
[/* your array */].map(formatSSN);
```

Comment: Unfortunately, my target environment does do the scientific notation at the number-to-string conversion. (See edit in IP, node.js gives me the same results as you) With `replace(/[^\d]/g, '')`, I get 10 digit strings because of the added exponent. If the SSN has a trailing zero, I get 9 digit strings where the last digit is the exponent.